# Pandas extract time of certain entry from rows with same date

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I'm fairly new to pandas and I'm trying find out how to extract time value from a DataFrame with rows that contain **same** and **different** dates, different sellers, different states, and time stamp for each state.

[image]

I need to extract rows where `State` = **"received"** shows up for **the first time** on **each date** from the DataFrame and for **each seller**.

As you can see in the screenshot above, the State **"received"** shows up twice on the same date for the same seller, but with different timestamp, I only need the rows where it appears for the first time.

PS. I haven't tried any code unfortunately, I searched a lot and came up empty. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df[df['State'] == 'Received'].groupby(['Seller', 'Date']).head(1)`?

Comment: `df[df['state'] == 'Received'].drop_duplicates(subset=['Seller', 'Date'])`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris that gives the desired result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Many thanks @ifly6, that also works as desired!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need `pandas.groupby`:

```
>>> df[df["State"]=="Received"].groupby(["Date", "Seller"])["Time"].first()
Date      Seller  
6/1/2021  Seller_1    8:00:36
          Seller_2    9:45:30
6/2/2021  Seller_1    8:00:36
          Seller_2    9:33:02
```

If you need *earliest* occurrence instead of *first*, you should use `min()` instead.

Comment: Thanks. In this case first and earliest happen to be the same and both above functions give the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
df[df['State'] == 'Received'].sort_values(by=['Seller', 'Date', 'Time']) \
    .drop_duplicates(subset=['Seller', 'Date'])
```

This would be mildly more performant than grouping.

Comment: OP wants the first and the not the earliest so probably don't sort?

Comment: My interpretation of 'first' was a more lay-person 'first received' rather than 'first encountered in this dataset'. If, of course, the OP meant 'first' as in 'first encountered', the OP can just omit the `sort_values` call.

Comment: @ifly6, thanks for the solution. `sort_values` seems to give a better organization to the DataFrame and same desired outcome for the first "received" on each date for each seller.